# Create a second value from html range slider

Tags: javascript, html, variables, slider, range

I'm a complete newbie to Javascript, I have taken a demo html slider and everything is working OK;

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("first");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="50" max="<?php echo round($widthhugemm); ?>" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
   <p>
      Size: <span id="first"></span>mm
    </p>
</div>
```

I now want to generate a second value from the slider value, this value will be dependant on the selected value - so not a second slider handle - I want to perform a simple multiplication from a variable and output that to a second span ID like this;

```
Size: <span id="first"></span>mm x <span id="second">mm</span>
```

I've been able to create a second output by duplicating the getElementByID by creating new variables and span IDs, I just cannot work out how to perform a multiplication on the initial slider value and create a new value (variable) with the answer and output it.

I hope all that makes sense and thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: Ok let me see if I'm sure of what you're asking... You want for example when I change the slider once I get 55 and output it to the first span then change it and get 60 and output it to the second span?

Comment: No, both values are generated at the same time, so when the slider is moved to 55 for example, the javascript will perform a multiplication to that value and output both the slider value of 55 and the second value (60 for example).

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 range input](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.range.html) only accepts one input!
You can use something like the [jQuery UI range](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) slider for that task.

Comment: I only want one input, but I want two outputs via a multiplication on that slider value.

Comment: Now I got it, just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
<input type="range" name="range" min="50" max="100" id="range" /><br>

<span id="first"></span> x <span id="second"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var r = document.getElementById('range');
    var first = document.getElementById('first');
    var sec = document.getElementById('second');
    flag = true;
    r.oninput = function(){
        first.innerHTML = this.value;
        second.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

Then I guess you would just need this

Comment: Thank you - although I'm really sorry - I misread your comment. The second value should not be generated on a second move of the slider. It should happen at the same time as the first move, so I think it is much simpler that your code here. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, that's great and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can understand exactly how it works since you are a junior, but it is certainly not the more optimised way!

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var first = document.getElementById("first");
var second = document.getElementById("second");

first.innerHTML = slider.value;
second.innerHTML = slider.value * 2;

slider.oninput = function() {
  first.innerHTML = this.value;
  second.innerHTML = this.value * 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="50" max="<?php echo round($widthhugemm); ?>" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
   <p>
      Size: <span id="first"></span>mm * <span id="second"></span>mm
    </p>
</div>
```